# Android back button not working for multiple activities

Tags: android, back-button

I am new to Android.

I have `three activities A, B, and C`.

In the `activity B`, I have a `listView` with the list of items. `On clicking each item, I want to show item details in the third activity`. It is working fine.

But while click on the back button of the third activity in an emulator it shows me that my application has stopped working.

I am not able to redirect to the second activity.

But `from the second activity,` I can come `back to the first activity`.

How can I resolve this problem?

**In activity C**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String displayTitle = extras.getString("title");
        String displayPrice = extras.getString("price");
        String BasicInfo = extras.getString("BasicInfo");
        try {
            BasicInfoobj = new JSONObject(BasicInfo);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_txtTitle);
        txtPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_txtPrice);
        txtLocation =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_txtLocation);
        txtTitle.setText(displayTitle);
        txtPrice.setText(displayPrice);

    }
```

**In Activity B**

```
private class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {
        public myListAdapter()
        {
            super(ResultActivity.this,R.layout.item_view,itemList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String CurrentImage="";
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null)
            {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
            }

            //populate the list
            //find the item to work with
            final Items CurrentItem = itemList.get(position);
            //fill the view

            TextView title =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_imageTitle);
            title.setText(CurrentItem.GetItemTitle());

            CurrentImage = CurrentItem.GetImgUrl();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            new ImageLoadTask(CurrentImage, imageView).execute();

            TextView Price =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_itemPrice);
            Price.setText(CurrentItem.GetPrice());

            title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("title",CurrentItem.GetItemTitle());
                    extras.putString("price",CurrentItem.GetPrice());
                    extras.putString("basicURL",CurrentItem.GetImgUrl());
                    extras.putString("ImageUrl",CurrentItem.GetImgSuperUrl());
                    extras.putString("BasicInfo",CurrentItem.GetBasicInfo().toString());
                    extras.putString("SellerInfo",CurrentItem.GetSellerInfo().toString());
                    extras.putString("ShippingInfo",CurrentItem.GetShippingInfo().toString());
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return itemView;
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: at least add the crash stack trace... and the crashing Activity code (onResume, onActivityResult, etc)

Comment: Add stacktrace...and code of crashed activity..

Comment: Without code and stack trace how can we help you??

Comment: Post the code of B activity. Have you implemented any code in onResume of activity B???

Comment: Unfortunately  its not logging any stack trace too.I just showing in the emulator that "unfortunately yourApp has stopped ".I am able to come back to the second activity using the below back button not the back button on the top.

Comment: @PiyushGupta due to privacy policy I will not be able to post my code.

Comment: @codemaster001 what privacy policy ? how can we help you then?

Comment: in the activity C my code is like this:

Comment: If you refuse to provide any details that are required to solve your problem, you won't get any help from us.

Comment: are you using onResume mehod on activity B or post onBackPressed method code of activity C

Answer (score 0):

Add proper code in Activity C:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Activity:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code and add this to control the back press:

```java
@override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```